How to associate KQL syntax with a YAML property in VSCode
I often have scenarios where I have a file using a data format (e.g. YAML, JSON) within which I have some property that needs to store a code snippet (e.g. KQL, SQL, JS, etc).  Is there a way for me to setup syntax support for both languages?  I realise that may be contradictory since the inner code is just a string from the parent document's perspective, but perhaps I could specify where this string value is more than a string; e.g. for YAML documents I could use YAML tags to specificy language support requirements.
To make a less open ended question: How could I implement syntax support (e.g. syntax highlighting) for KQL within YAML?
As an example, my YAML may look like this (the !kql tag is just a suggestion of how I'd flag this field as requiring KQL support vs being an arbitrary string value).
name: stack overflow demo
description: |
  Lists all virtual machines
  Note: this is just an arbitrary multi-line string
query: !kql | 
  resources |
  where type =~ 'microsoft.compute/virtualmachines'
  // Note: this is a multi-line string which is also a valid KQL query


https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/1751#issuecomment-919998146

read the language grammar docs, and inject the grammar of the other language, you can see it in action if you use Markdown files and specify the language of triple backtick code blocks

Theres a couple extensions providing that functionality.
ruschaaf.extended-embedded-languages
harrydowning.yaml-embedded-languages
marketplace
if they don't support your language, simply just ask them in their github repos
